# MySQL Fulltext search results in html content

Tags: php, html, mysql, full-text-search

I have a database with oages of content. The content is in html format. I want to make all that content searchable so I figured a fulltext search would be best. I have the query setup below:

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST ('search');
```

That gives me a list of pages, however, sometimes there are multiple matches on those pages. I want to pull out the matches with some of the content surrounding it to show little snippets of the results on the search results page.

I am using PHP as well which will be running the query.

Comment: What columns are in the `pages` table? That will help us help you with a workable query.

Comment: what about using like for a single keyword:  LIKE '%keyword%'

Comment: The pages table has a columns 'id (int)', 'page_number (int)', 'type (char 1)', 'content (LONGTEXT)', 'created_at (DATETIME)', and 'updated_at (DATETIME)'.

Comment: It might be easier to do this in PHP vs the query.  Something like - `explode` your content field on your search words, and show the 50 characters/words before + your search  + 50 characters/words after.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the LIKE clause to do some simple string matching, along the lines of:

```
SELECT content FROM pages WHERE content LIKE '%keyword%';
```

Comment: I understand how to perform the search. Basically, when I get the results, I want to be able to create a snippet showing the results and some of the content around it.

Comment: You could use strpos to determine the position of the start of your text. Then paste x-amount of characters before it and after the keyword.

Comment: The search term can appear multiple times on the same page though.